# Button not showing in ScrollView kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want every time the `def send_message` is clicked, a new button is added to the rightside of the scrollview, the code is not raising any errors but it is not displaying anything on the Scrollview. Here is the code below. I would appreciate if it can be looked at thank you.

```
class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScrollableLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.chathistory = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical", spacing = 5, padding = [10, 10])
        self.add_widget(self.chathistory)



class Chat(Screen):


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Chat, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.localId = None

        self.cols = 1
        self.rows = 2

        self.history = ScrollableLabel(size_hint_y = None)
        self.add_widget(self.history)
        self.messagebutton = Button(text="Send", font_size = 20, font_name= "fonts/Qanelas-Heavy.otf", background_color= (0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0), background_normal= '', pos_hint= {"right": 1,"down": 1}, size_hint= [0.2, 0.1])
        self.messagebutton.bind(on_release = self.send_message)
        self.add_widget(self.messagebutton)


        self.messagetextinput = TextInput(width=Window.size[0]*0.8, hint_text= "Write a message", font_name= "fonts/Qanelas-Light.otf", size_hint= [0.8, 0.1], pos_hint= {"left": 1,"down": 1})
        self.add_widget(self.messagetextinput)


        Window.bind(on_key_down=self.on_key_down)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_text_input, 1)

    def on_key_down(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode == 40:
            self.send_message(None)



    def on_enter(self, *args):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        self.chatdestination = Label(text = firebase.get("/users/" + app.localId, 'first name') + " " + firebase.get('/users/' + app.localId, 'last name'),
                                     pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.95}, size_hint = [0.8, 0.1], color = (0, 0, 0, 1), font_name = "fonts/Qanelas-Light.otf")

        self.add_widget(self.chatdestination)

    def send_message(self, _):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        message = self.messagetextinput.text
        if message:
            database.child("messages").child(app.localId).update({self.localId: message})
            self.chatbubble = Button(text = self.messagetextinput.text, background_color= [0.925, 0.925, 0.925, 0.003],background_normal = '', pos_hint = {'right': 1}, size_hint= [0.2, 0.1])
            self.history.chathistory.add_widget(self.chatbubble)
            self.history.scroll_to(self.chatbubble)
            self.messagetextinput.text = ""


            Clock.schedule_once(self.focus_text_input, 0.1)


    def focus_text_input(self, _):
        self.messagetextinput.focus = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, widget inside the ScrollView should have one of the size_hint parameter deactivated (equals None). If you want to scroll vertically, then size_hint_y of the BoxLayout (and children) should be None, because if you won't do that all your widgets will fit the ScrollView and there will be nothing to scroll.
And at second, if we deactivate the height hint, BoxLayout can do something wrong. So better to tell it to set the minimum height possible for child widget (it would be height of the child widget actually).

So:

```
class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScrollableLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # add size_hint_y = None
        self.chathistory = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical", spacing = 5, padding = [10, 10], size_hint_y = None)
        # set height
        self.chathistory.bind(minimum_height=self.chathistory.setter('height'))
        self.add_widget(self.chathistory)
...
...
# set size_hint_y to None also
self.chatbubble = Button(text = self.messagetextinput.text, background_color= [0.925, 0.925, 0.925, 0.003],background_normal = '', pos_hint = {'right': 1}, size_hint= [0.2, None])
```

Comment: Try to set 'size_hint' of the ScrollableLabel to (1, 1) (or else, but not None). And try to add some widget to the ScrollView by kv language, will it appear?